# I am trying to disable the /decrypt endpoint in Spring cloud config server so that anyone with access to /decrypt endpoint wont be able to decrypt

Tags: spring, encryption, endpoint, password-encryption, spring-cloud-config-server

with /decrypt endpoint availble for anyone with access I feel the encryption is not secure and its compramised

Is there any way we can disable the decrypt endpoint?

url: http://localhost:23000/encrypt
body: hello
response: 8c27f45094636aee57e2e132f

with decrypt enabled we can get back the password

url: http://localhost:23000/encrypt
body: 8c27f45094636aee57e2e132f
response: hello

Answer (score 1):

Add the Spring Security starter to your pom.xml file:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

With Spring Security on the classpath, [all endpoints require authorization](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#web.security) by default. Configure Spring Security to deny access to the /decrypt endpoint while allowing unauthenticated access to configuration data:

```java
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class SecurityConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests(requests ->
        requests
            .mvcMatchers("/decrypt").denyAll()
            .anyRequest().permitAll());
    return http.build();
  }
}
```